# Eclipse RCP - what plugins/feature should be added to Eclipse product and how make it similar to Eclipse SDK/Standard

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

There is Nodeclipse project http://www.nodeclipse.org/ that is a set of Eclipse plugins. I want to make Eclipse distribution for all major OSes that would have Eclipse SDK/Standard as base.

There is an Eclipse plugin project with `product` definitions. I [got hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040400/how-to-create-ide-that-would-have-eclipse-sdk-standard-as-basis) that `org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench` should be included (in .product?).

**What is full list of plugins to be included? (Where exactly to check?)**

How to accomplish building this Eclipse IDE distribution?

Comment: Well, what are you trying to accomplish?  Who would this distribution be for?  What functionality do the current distributions lack?  I guess if you are making your own Eclipse distribution, you can put whatever plugins you want in it.  It just depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to build Eclipse IDE. What I have is just base Eclipse RCP with no workbench, EGIT, JDT, Marketplace. How to put those plugins?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is use a `.product` file with `The product configuration is based on` set to `features`. Then in the dependencies you can just list the features you want (for example `org.eclipse.platform`), this is a much smaller list than individual plugins.

You will have to create a feature for your own plugins to do this and put that in the dependencies.

For example:

```xml
<features>
  <feature id="myproduct.feature"/>
  <feature id="org.eclipse.rcp"/>
  <feature id="org.eclipse.platform"/>
  <feature id="org.eclipse.jdt"/>
  <feature id="org.eclipse.cvs"/>
</features>
```

is an extract from a `.product` file including the standard Eclipse IDE, JDT and CVS code.